# How to get high quality of images in Opencart's slideshow

Tags: slider, opencart

I am using original slideshow in Opencart. When I upload images the quality doesn't vary, but in slider the qualities are lower like original images.

Comment: What images are You using? JPEGs, PNGs, GIFs? When working with (resizing) JPEGs and GIFs within PHP there is always some more-or-less visible quality loss - which is there also for PNGs but is rather less than less visible... And I could also ask **whether the images You upload are the same size or bigger** than desired banner dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you'll need to upload your banners at exactly the right size and then change some code so it doesn't resize it. Open `/catalog/controller/module/slideshow.php` and find this code

```
'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height'])
```

change it to

```
'image' => HTTPS_SERVER . 'image/' . $result['image']
```

Note that this assumes a fairly recent version of OpenCart - older versions you would be better off using

```
'image' => HTTPS_IMAGE . $result['image']
```

Comment: @ViktorR Are you sure it was slideshow and not the banner?

Comment: Yes you are right it is banner which is in the slider

Comment: @ViktorR instead of `slideshow.php` above, find `banner.php` and apply the same change

Comment: +1 for the exact size of banner images though no other code changes are required - if the original image has exact dimensions it is not resized in the end at all. I used this approach with animated GIFs as banners - when uploaded at exact dimensions they are not resized and work/animate correctly (while after resizing the animation is gone with the wind).